# How to connect RStudio to SQL DB on MacBook Pro M2?

Tags: odbc, rstudio, database-connection, sqlconnection

I have a MacBook Pro M2.
I would like to connect to my SQL DB through RStudio but I cannot do it because I get below issue:
**Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1135: 00000: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found
**
Please could you advise if it is possible or not?
If possible, please could you advise what are the all steps to make it connected?
I tried lots of ways to do so...

I tried to install SQL Driver from [Microsoft Offical Website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-ver16), but It didn't help me.
In addition, I tried to use some open source solutions, but they also didn't help me.